# MOSS 2007 <SharePoint:SPSqlDataSource /> compatibility with SQL Server 2012 version database

Tags: 2007, sql

We have a MOSS 2007 version sharepoint site, and a database in Sql server 2005 ver (a application specific database with all required tables)

we are accessing the data (by using <SharePoint:SPSqlDataSource />) and writing it back (by using <asp:sqldatasource />) from the MOSS 2007 SP2 front end.

Now the question is:

we have plan to migrate the application specific database from SQL Server 2005 to 2012.

so is SPSqlDataSource & <asp:SqlDataSource /> will support pulling data from Sql 2012 server ?

Thanks,

Girish

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of the Office SharePoint Server 2007 does not support SQL Server 2012 or later versions of SQL Server! So I think `<SharePoint:SPSqlDataSource />`will not work.

For more details check [SQL Server 2012 not supported on WSS 3.0/MOSS 2007 and versions previous than SharePoint 2010 SP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvarro/2012/04/27/sql-server-2012-not-supported-on-wss-3-0moss-2007-and-versions-previous-than-sharepoint-2010-sp1/)